# Navigate through Page with Arrow Keys

Tags: javascript, html

I want to allow a user to navigate through my page with the arrow keys on their keyboard. For every press, I want them to be able to pass to the next section in an index unless in focused on an input field.

The basic structure of my code is this:

```
  <body>
      <section id="main">
          <!--CONTENT-->
      </section>
      <section id="creation">
          <!--CONTENT-->
      </section>
      <section id="about">
          <!--CONTENT-->
      </section>
      <section id="contact">
          <!--CONTENT-->
      </section>
  </body>


section {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: I'm aware you can do this with `tabindex`, but not with arrow keys. Maybe a use of the ``onkeypress``/``keypressup`` event listeners?

Answer (score 0):

I made a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k8zooca0/19/) with my vision how it can be achieved. I assume that you can use jQuery. Pressing up or down arrows moves a user to the next or previous section and highlights it with red borders. Code:

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
  var $activeSection = $("section.active"),
    $newActiveSection;
    if (e.which == 38) {
    // Up
        $newActiveSection = $activeSection.prev("section");
    if(!$newActiveSection.length) {
        $newActiveSection = $("section").last();
    }
  } else if (e.which == 40) {
    // Down
    $newActiveSection = $activeSection.next("section");
    if(!$newActiveSection.length) {
        $newActiveSection = $("section").first();
    }
  }
  $activeSection.removeClass("active");
  $newActiveSection.addClass("active");
  scrollToObject($newActiveSection);

  e.preventDefault();
});

function scrollToObject(object) {
    $(window).scrollTop(object.offset().top);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add javascript code for that. seems like JQuery can be the right tool for the job. Should be something like this:

```
$(function() {
  var allowKeypressNavigation = true;
  var $body = $('body');
  var $activeSection = $('#main');

  //set active section
  function setPrevSectionActive() {
    if($activeSection.is(':first-child')) {
      $activeSection = $activeSection.siblings().last();
    } else {
      $activeSection = $activeSection.prev();
    }
  }

  function setNextSectionActive() {
    if($activeSection.is(':last-child')) {
      $activeSection = $activeSection.siblings().first();
    } else {
      $activeSection = $activeSection.next();
    }
  }

  //scroll to active section
  function scrollToActiveSection() {
    var location = $activeSection.offset().top;
    $body.scrollTop(location);
  }

  //disable keyboard navigation when input in focus
  $('input').on("focus", function(e){
    allowKeypressNavigation = false;
  }).on("blur", function(e){
    allowKeypressNavigation = true;
  });

  //assing event to document
  $(document).on("keydown", function(e){
    if(allowKeypressNavigation) {
      var keyCode = e.keyCode;
      if(keyCode==38) {
        //UP pressed
        setPrevSectionActive();
        scrollToActiveSection();
      } else if(keyCode==40) {
        //DOWN pressed
        setNextSectionActive();
        scrollToActiveSection();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

I've add a [working example on plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/nNkLL7kF8699uWzh37wn?p=preview) for this one.